# Link/Chain CSS Transitions

Tags: css

I know this should be a no-brainer, but for some reason I really just cannot figure out how to link my CSS transitions... I am attaching a website with widgets that act how I want mine to act: https://kion.io/resources

I love that when you hover on the widget, all CSS transitions happen at the same time over that one div/a href

I am attempting to do the same, and I have written all of my code but I have to hover individually over my elements... this is for a site that is not yet done, but I will post a link to the page that I am referring to. Specifically focusing on the widgets in the middle of the page. They scale up, BUT I want the arrows to move to the right when you hover over the entire div like in Kion's site. I can only figure out how to make them move when you hover over them specifically.

My site: https://cloudshape.net/cloudshape/

My code:

```css
/*WIDGETS*/

.card a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.card a:hover {
  color: black;
}

.card {
  font-family: 'helvetica', sans-serif;
  margin: 25px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  background-image: url('https://cloudshape.net/wp- 
 content/uploads/2022/02/clear-bg.png');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: background-image 2s ease-in-out;
}

.white-square {
  width: 310px;
  height: 330px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px #202020;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform .4s ease-in-out, border .4s ease-in-out;
}


/*WIDGET ARROW BUTTONS*/

.btn img {
  width: 80px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-left: 120px;
}

.btn img:hover {
  margin-left: 130px;
}

.btn img {
  transition: margin-left .7s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <a href="">
    <div class="white-square">
      <span class="icon"><img alt="security" src="https://cloudshape.net/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/shielddot-color.png"/></span>
      <h5>Dev(Sec)Ops/SRE<br>Architecture & Modernization</h5>

      <p>Short for development, security and operations — automates the integration of security at every phase of the software development lifecycle.</p>
      <span class="btn"><img alt="button" src="https://cloudshape.net/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/arrow.png"/></span>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please ensure that the code present on this site demonstrates what you've tried and where you're having an issue. People who answer your question should not have to go to another site to answer the question. See [ask] for more tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this CSS rule to target your arrow when your white square is hovered :

```css
.white-square:hover .btn img {
  margin-left: 130px;
}
```

Comment: Add some explanation in your answer to make it more easy to understand